# Primefaces ckEditor not show image

Tags: java, image, primefaces, ckeditor

i'm using CKEditor with primefaces extensions and java. I can successfully add a local image in the editor, but when i save, the validation remove the tag , so i lose the image. Nothing else is removed, only the  tag. Even if i set the bean value previously, the editor remove the tag reading the string.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Please did you finally get a solution to this problem? If so please can you put it here?